# iOS) addsubview tabBarController.view into ParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, addsubview

I want to addsubview 'tabView' but there is no tabView.

What I want to make is the UIViewController having fixed view at the top and bottom of viewcontroller and 'tabView' between these fixed views at the top and bottom.

Like this, below is the xib of Parent UIViewController : [image]

As you see I made a in-between view between top and botoom view.
So what i thought is after importing OtherTabBarController into ParentUIViewController , addsubview OtherTabBarController.view into in-between view.

But it doesn't work properly, it just shows me blurred view.
[image]

Is my logit is wrong? Anything I can solve this problem?

Comment: In iOS the UITabBarController will always display its tabs at the bottom. You will have to subclass UITabBarController in order to achieve, what you want to do. 

I'd guess that it was easier to develop something like UITabBarController from scratch that suits your needs.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I already subclass and made it. and that's not the core problem...

Comment: Hmmm... try defining a Container View in the parent and assign OtherTabBarController.view to that one. 
If you have difficulties with that, then add a subview to OtherTabBarController.view that just fills the full view. Add all other subviews of OtherTabBarController.view to this new view. The new view is then some sort of proxy which you add as subview to ParentUIViewController. But I don't think this proxy view is required. The view contrainer should help solving your problem.